# M option in make command, Makefile

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

```
make -C ~/kernel-2.6 M=`pwd` modules
```

What is the meaning in M='pwd' in the line above ?

I could not understand the explanation :

> The M= option causes that makefile to move back into your module source
>   directory before trying to build the modules target.

Can you make this more clear ?

Answer (score 36):

`M` is not an option for `make`. Note it lacks the hyphen. `M` is a variable assigned to the execution of `make`. If `make` executes a `Makefile` script, this script can read the variable `M` and use its contents.

In the example you provide, `make` will read `Makefile` in `~/kernel-2.6` and assign your present working directory to variable `M`. Typically, this will allow for `make` to return to your current directory after processing `Makefile`.

Comment: Not "after processing the Makefile" (that happens anyway, just by exiting), but "to find the sources when using the kernel Makefile". It's a pointer back to "here" from "there" in a module build.

Answer (score 22):

I had similar quiz with

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

Here the make is called within my project's directory. `-C` is make option:

> -C dir, --directory=dir
>               Change to directory dir before reading the makefiles or doing  anything  else.   If
>               multiple  -C  options  are  specified, each is interpreted relative to the previous
>               one: -C / -C etc is equivalent to -C /etc.  This is typically used  with  recursive
>               invocations of make.

`M` is not make option but argument passed to it. Since `-C` changes make directory we know that make will read make file in that directory. By inspection of make file in that directory I have discovered what it is going then to do with `M`:

From make file (named Makefile) in the directory pointed to by `-C` (btw it is kernel build directory):

```
# Use make M=dir to specify directory of external module to build
# Old syntax make ... SUBDIRS=$PWD is still supported
# Setting the environment variable KBUILD_EXTMOD takes precedence
ifdef SUBDIRS
  KBUILD_EXTMOD ?= $(SUBDIRS)
endif
```

Explanation from Linux Device Drivers, 3rd Edition, Jonathan Corbet et al.:

> This command starts by changing its directory to the one provided with
>   the -C option (that is, your kernel source directory). There it finds
>   the kernel's top-level makefile. The M= option causes that makefile to
>   move back into your module source directory before trying to build the
>   modules target.

Answer (score 11):

Read the manual for `make`:

```
-C dir, --directory=dir
            Change to directory dir before reading the makefiles or doing anything else.
```

Your invocation changes the directory to `~/kernel` and effectively calls `make` there, i.e. reading the `Makefile` from that directory. With the `M` variable, the makefile knows where your actual project files are and can change back to that location.

The point is that you don't write your own makefile, but use a single, once-and-for-all version.

Answer (score 6):

Other answers are mostly correct, but I want to tell you the way to learn it.

1. `M` is not a option
2. `M` is a variable in `Makefile`
3. so we should read the `Makefile` in the directory that the `make -C` changes to.

Read the Makefile: there are few comments:

```
# Use make M=dir to specify directory of external module to build
# Old syntax make ... SUBDIRS=$PWD is still supported
# Setting the environment variable KBUILD_EXTMOD take precedence
ifdef SUBDIRS
  KBUILD_EXTMOD ?= $(SUBDIRS)
endif

ifeq ("$(origin M)", "command line")
  KBUILD_EXTMOD := $(M)
endif
```

You can search for `KBUILD_EXTMOD`:

```
VPATH       := $(srctree)$(if $(KBUILD_EXTMOD),:$(KBUILD_EXTMOD))
module-dirs := $(addprefix _module_,$(KBUILD_EXTMOD))
```

That's how the kernel's `Makefile` can build your out-of-tree sources.

Answer (score 2):

The command to build an external module is:

```
    $ make -C <path_to_kernel_src> M=$PWD
```

The kbuild system knows that an external module is being built due to the "M=" option given in the command.

To build against the running kernel use:

```
    $ make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD
```

Answer (score 1):

In a Unix shell, writing `` `foobar` `` in the middle of a command means "run the command `foobar` and substitute its output here."

So including `` M=`pwd` `` in the `make` command means "run the `pwd` command to print the current working directory, and set the `M` variable to that value."

Comment: I didn;t understand the M= option

Comment: When `make` is building the kernel, before it tries to build the `modules` target it will change to the directory named in the `M` variable.