# Trying to make new driver gives "No rule to make target" for the .o file

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, linux-kernel

I am trying to modify a driver for an LCD display. My Makefile contains:

```
obj-m += dft0928.o

all:
    make -C /usr/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /usr/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

When I run "make" in the folder containing my source file (dft0928.c), I get this output:

```
make -C /usr/lib/modules/5.15.74-v7+/build M=/home/pi/software/driver modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.74-v7+'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/pi/software/driver/dft0928.o', needed by '/home/pi/software/driver/dft0928.mod'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1898: /home/pi/software/driver] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.74-v7+'
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 2
```

Where am I going wrong? All the existing guides that I can find suggest my Makefile should be sufficient.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301591/m-option-in-make-command-makefile

Comment: Not sure what "guides" you are following but the only correct directions are the ones in the kernel Documentation directory.  The latest version is here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/modules.html

Comment: @stark, I've read that page and what I am doing is correct, as far as I can tell. I tried splitting the Makefile into a Makefile and a Kbuild file but got exactly the same result.

Comment: @optimus_prime, I wasn't asking about the M option (I understand what it is doing), so I'm not sure why you pointed me at that page. Can you expand a little?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem - fat finger when writing Makefile. So stupid, just missed it every time I looked at it.

Comment: I don't understand what kind of solution this answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Tsyvarev didn't like my previous answer so just to make it very clear. The root of filename "dft0928.o" in the Makefile did not match the name of the source file, which is "dfr0928.c". Once I corrected that, it compiled no problem.

I then hit other problems, but that's another story.